# How to detect network change events asynchronously using c++ WinRT

Tags: c++, windows-runtime

```
networkStatusCallback = new NetworkStatusChangedEventHandler(OnNetworkStatusChange);
    if (!registeredNetworkStatusNotif)
    {
        NetworkInformation.NetworkStatusChanged += networkStatusCallback;
        registeredNetworkStatusNotif = true;
    }
```

I'm getting the error NetworkInformation.NetworkStatusChanged += networkStatusCallback

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Also please learn how to create a [mre]. Lastly please learn how to [edit] your questions to improve them.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

This will get you started.  It's some code I cobbled together.

It doesn't do error checking.  You should check the HRESULT or error code from each major function invoked below.

It doesn't show you how to implement `INetworkStatusChangedEventHandler`.  You have to implement an implementation of that class yourself using the standard COM principals.

You'll need to link with `runtimeobjects.lib` for RoGetActivationFactory.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <roapi.h>
#include <Windows.Networking.h>
#include <Windows.Networking.Connectivity.h>

using ABI::Windows::Networking::Connectivity::INetworkInformationStatics;
using ABI::Windows::Networking::Connectivity::INetworkStatusChangedEventHandler;

int main()
{
    CoInitialize(nullptr);
    HSTRING hstr = nullptr;
    IActivationFactory* pFactory = nullptr;
    INetworkInformationStatics* pStatics = nullptr;
    EventRegistrationToken token = {};

    const wchar_t* interfaceName = RuntimeClass_Windows_Networking_Connectivity_NetworkInformation;
    ::WindowsCreateString(interfaceName, (DWORD)(wcslen(interfaceName)), &hstr);

    ::RoGetActivationFactory(hstr, IID_IActivationFactory, (void**)&pFactory);
    WindowsDeleteString(hstr);

    INetworkStatusChangedEventHandler* pHandler = <ptr to com object you create that implements INetworkStatusChangedEventHandler>

    pFactory->QueryInterface(&pStatics);

    pStatics->add_NetworkStatusChanged(pHandler, &token);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I'm looking to implement using C++ WinRT API

Comment: Can you please help me how to implement using C++ WinRT