# WinUI3 : Handle network change event in WinUI3 desktop with c++

Tags: c++, windows-runtime, winui-3, cppwinrt

I'm working on the WinUI3 desktop application in C++. I was checking how we can get an event when the network to which system is connected to changes. I came across [NetworkInformation.NetworkStatusChanged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.networking.connectivity.networkinformation.networkstatuschanged?view=winrt-22621) event. But I was not able to find any example of its implementation in C++.

[NetworkStatusChangedEventHandler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.networking.connectivity.networkstatuschangedeventhandler?view=winrt-22621) says it has one parameter which is IInspectable object.

i tried

`static void NetworkStatusChange(winrt::Windows::Foundation::IInspectable const& sender);`

But it gave this error

`*\Generated Files\winrt\Windows.Networking.Connectivity.h(2213,81): error C2297: '.*': not valid as right operand has type 'const M'`

Can you please help me with help me with how to implement NetworkStatusChanged event in WinUI3 C++ desktop application correctly.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you can do it with [C++/WinRT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/cpp-and-winrt-apis/intro-to-using-cpp-with-winrt):

add this into the pch.h:

```
#include <winrt/Windows.Networking.Connectivity.h>
```

add this somewhere in your code:

```
// you can instead add a "using namespace Windows::Networking::Connectivity;"
// and use NetworkInformation directly if you prefer
Windows::Networking::Connectivity::NetworkInformation info{};
info.NetworkStatusChanged([=](auto&&...) // sender is not super interesting in this type of event so I've not declared it
{
    // do your stuff here
    MessageBox(nullptr, L"Something Changed!", L"Network", 0);
});
```

If you prefer the "raw" C/C++ way, there's an example here: [How to detect network change events asynchronously using c++ WinRT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69158188/how-to-detect-network-change-events-asynchronously-using-c-winrt)

Comment: Do not use `[&]` in asynchronous callbacks. By the time the callback occurs, the referenced objects have probably been destroyed.

Comment: Thank you this was very helpful, can you please explain the parameters [=] and (...) used in NetworkStatusChanged() function.

Comment: The `(...)` should be `(auto&&...)`. Otherwise, you run afoul of [**expr.call**](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/expr.call#12): (variadic function parameters): "Passing a potentially-evaluated argument of a scoped enumeration type or of a class type ([class]) having an eligible non-trivial copy constructor, an eligible non-trivial move constructor, or a non-trivial destructor ([special]), with no corresponding parameter, is **conditionally-supported with implementation-defined semantics**." Some implementations (e.g. clang) raise a compile-time and/or runtime error, which are both valid.

Comment: @RaymondChen - Thanks again. Strange I didn't even see the warning (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/compiler-warnings/compiler-warning-level-4-c4840) in Output/ErrorList windows. (c++ lambda are so complicated vs C# ones...)

Comment: @Harshith - [=] means in lambda code you capture all used variables (if you want to use info for example) by copy. (auto&&...) means you don't want to identify/use the parameters but still want the system to compile. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/lambda-expressions-in-cpp